# Jquery mobile: How to pass params to the page (hash URL)?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've got a list with elements that contain links:

```html
<a class="ui-link-inherit" href="#card_ops?card=1111">
```

and

```html
<a class="ui-link-inherit" href="#card_ops?card=2222">
```

1) I click on first link my location in browsers changes on `#card_ops?card=1111` - goes to page #card_ops.
2) I return on the previour page using back button.
3) Click on the second link with `href="#card_ops?card=2222"` my location in browsers changes AGAIN on `#card_ops?card=1111 not 222`

Is it possible to pass the params to the pages in jq mobile?

Comment: Work in progress but if you inspect the element you will see the value http://jsfiddle.net/G5fhn/12/ jQM Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution I've found. Not sure how well it works as I haven't tried it.

http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2011/12/passing-data-between-pages-in-jquery-mobile/